# How to Add Js Script Ads in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-template, ads

I am new to Angular 2 , I had developed a Web-site now I want to add ads but unfortunately ads are in Js formate they are working if i add in index.html page but i want to modulate their location and type in differnt pages can any one help me with it, here is a basic format of Ads script that I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
( function() {
if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
var unit =  {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"Sunny6142","width":550,"height":250,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
}());
</script>
```